# how to insert key value pair in an order using json functions in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I want to Insert "middle_name" : "k" in between first_name and last_name

```
{
  "first_name" : "Sammy",
  "last_name" : "Shark"
}
```

I expect the key to be inserted like this :

```
{
  "first_name" : "Sammy",
  "Middle_name":"k", 
  "last_name" : "Shark"
}
```

but, when using json_insert() or Json_set() result is

```
{
  "first_name" : "Sammy",
  "last_name" : "Shark",
  "Middle_name":"k"
}
```

Comment: `... To make lookups more efficient, it also sorts the keys of a JSON object. You should be aware that the result of this ordering is subject to change and not guaranteed to be consistent across releases. ...`, see [11.6 The JSON Data Type :: Normalization, Merging, and Autowrapping of JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-normalization).

Comment: You must choose between an ordered array and a key-value set.  There is no JSON construct that does both.